# Preventing PyPubSub "Dead Listener" error

Tags: python, garbage-collection, tornado, publish-subscribe, pypubsub

I'm using the package [PyPubSub](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/) in a Python project so I can subscribe methods to channels and publish on those channels while the program runs.

As part of a stress test, I set the program to run over and over for multiple hours. (Each run takes about 6 hours.)

Everything seems to work fine for the first 20 hours, but after 20 hours, I get this message: "RuntimeError: BUG: Dead Listener called, still subscribed!"

From what I can tell, a "Dead Listener" is a listener (a method that is subscribed to a channel) that has been garbage collected. (PyPubSub has a weak reference to each channel's listeners, but these references aren't enough to keep the listeners from being garbage collected.)

This error isn't enough to kill my entire program, but it is enough to disconnect my server's websocket connection to the client. (I implemented the server using [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).)

If this was caused by the listeners being garbage collected without being officially unsubscribed, would this issue have come up after one run rather than three or four? I tried to remove all references to the listeners at the end of each run; I thought they would be garbage collected then.

Should I try to manually unsubscribe the listeners at the end of each run?

How do I keep this "Dead Listener" error from happening?

EDIT: I started manually unsubscribing the listeners at the end of each run using pub.unsubscribe(), and that seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Are you using pypubsub from multiple threads?

Comment: Good to know that unsubscribe() did the job, thanks for posting update.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Calling unsubscribe() when using PyPubSub in a threaded application fixes this issue as shown in the 2nd comment above & at the end of the question.

In addition calling unsubAll() at the end of unit tests also helps where you may have set-up complex subscriptions ~ put it in the tearDown()